# Easily copy current command line in GNU-Screen

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I want to copy the text `command to copy` in the current command line in a very fast way.

```
user@server:~/somepath$ command to copy
```

I know this way:

1. Use `Ctrl+[` to enter copy mode,
2. Navigate by arrow keys to beginning of the word `command`
3. Copy until the end of line

I will use the copied text in another window of the same Screen session.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101198/how-to-send-command-output-to-gnu-screens-copy-mode-buffer) is a great way to do it. If you create the script (created as a function named `screen_send_to_copy_mode` in the post above) as `~/bin/screencp`, you can do the following:

1 press `[Ctrl-A] A` (goes to start of line)
2 type `echo` (including a space after)
3 press `[Ctrl-E]` (end of line)
4 type  `|screencp`

Depending on how fast you type and how long is the command, this would save you a few seconds of life ;)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method you can use is after entering copy mode, send a page up command, hit <kbd>pg-up</kbd>, hit <kbd>/</kbd> type `command`, press <kbd>enter</kbd> then hit <kbd>$</kbd> followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>.  This will copy from current position to end of line.